# make a section visible by hovering over paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I know this question already has some answers, but I can't figure out how to make a section visible when it has the `display:none` property. I need to make it visible when I mouse over some paragraphs. Here's my code:

```css
.buttons {
  width: 97px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("/res/downArrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.buttons:hover > .label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url("/res/upArrow.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: visible;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  top: 35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #3f84f2;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <div class="menu left">
    <div class="logo left"></div>
    <p class="buttons left">REVIEWS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">FEATURES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">GUIDES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">VIDEOS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">GALLERIES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">FORUMS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">EVENTS</p>
    <div class="left">
      <input type="text" value="Search Products & Articles" />
    </div>
    <div class="login-icon right"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="label"></section>
```

For example! check out this site please `http://www.engadget.com/` and see the behavior of the menu. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not be done with CSS unless you move `.label` into the same container as your `.buttons`. CSS has no parent selector to traverse the DOM like javascript does so the element has to be either a sibling or a descendant:

```
<section class="header">
        <div class="menu left">
            <div class="logo left"></div>
            <p class="buttons left">REVIEWS</p>
            <p class="buttons left">FEATURES</p>
            <p class="buttons left">GUIDES</p>
            <p class="buttons left">VIDEOS</p>
            <p class="buttons left">GALLERIES</p>
            <p class="buttons left">FORUMS</p>
            <p class="buttons left">EVENTS</p>
            <div class="left">
                <input type="text" value="Search Products & Articles" />
            </div>
            <div class="login-icon right"></div>
            <section class="label">SHOW THE TEXT</section>
    </div>
    </section>
```

And also you're using `display: none` on `label` but calling `visibility:visible` on hover. It needs to be another display property other than hidden:

```
.buttons:hover ~ .label{ //target sibling 
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #000;
   background-image: url("/res/upArrow.png");
   cursor: pointer;
   display:block; //add
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5dtmcjd/2/)

If you want to do this with your current HTML structure you can use a `.hover()` function in jQuery pretty simply:

```
$(".buttons").hover(function(){

    $(".label").toggle();

});
```

[**JS EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5dtmcjd/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the ~ tip. I didn't know this option and it'll certainly help me in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display:block;` instead of visibility as you're hiding by using `display:none`:

```
.buttons:hover ~ .label{/*used ~ instead of > to refer nextAll siblings*/
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    background-image: url("/res/upArrow.png");
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

If you have used `visibility:hidden` in label then only needed to use `visibility:visible` in `.buttons:hover > .label`

And you should use html like this:

```
<section class="header">
  <div class="menu left">
    <div class="logo left"></div>
    <p class="buttons left">REVIEWS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">FEATURES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">GUIDES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">VIDEOS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">GALLERIES</p>
    <p class="buttons left">FORUMS</p>
    <p class="buttons left">EVENTS</p>
    <div class="left">
      <input type="text" value="Search Products & Articles" />
    </div>
    <div class="login-icon right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="label"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: That won't work as the `.label` isn't a child of the `.buttons`. He either needs to move the `.label` inside the `.buttons` or use JavaScript to make the label visible.

Comment: Looking at `.buttons:hover > .label`, I don't see any `.label` element that is a direct child of `.buttons` in OP's markup.